# Unity3D - Problems after reloading scene via Application.LoadLevel

Tags: unity-game-engine, reload, destroy, scene

I have a problem...

There are four scenes in my game: An opening scene, a scene to select players, the actual game play scene, and the game over scene.

I am running into problems when I load my actual play scene additional times

```
Application.LoadLevel("Let's play the game!")
```

This is how I am leaving this scene:

```
if(GUI.Button (new Rect (x, y, w, h), "Quit", buttonStyle))
{
   Application.Quit();
   Application.LoadLevel("Opening Screen");
}
```

When I load my desired level a second time, the camera is supposed to be following the first player. This is not happening. I provide an option to "restart", which would resolve that issue, but I don't want this event happening in the first place.

More serious concerns GameObjects that were dynamically loaded. I am receiving "'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it." I am not sure where this is coming from, as I don't see where I had previously called "Destroy" anywhere. Furthermore, the objects dynamically created do appear in the hierarchy, when I am running the app inside Unity.

I think the root of my problem lies with the failing camera, but I'm not sure how to approach fixing it.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to make sure to call [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) to keep your object in memory between level loads:

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObjectToPreserve);
```

Also, the following code from your example will quit your application before it can load your "Opening Screen":

```
if(GUI.Button (new Rect (x, y, w, h), "Quit", buttonStyle))
{
   Application.Quit();
   Application.LoadLevel("Opening Screen");
}
```

Remove the line "Application.Quit()" if you intend to return to the opening screen.  You won't see this problem in the editor's preview mode because Application.Quit() doesn't do anything there.

Comment: Yes, remove Application.Quit(); That will actually close your game outside of the Unity Editor.

Comment: You guys are fast!

Thanks for the warning regarding Application.Quit().

I began to comment a bunch of source code and have isolated my problem. My camera GameObject is linked to a script which is failing when the desired level is reloaded. Apparently, that error has caused a train-wreck effect throughout the level.

Comment: I've fixed everything. I was able to find several areas where validation on objects was missing. That eliminated the "'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it".

With regards to the camera, I have a question: Are calls to the GUI.* restricted to only inside OnGUI()? I make calls inside OnGUI() which references GUI.Button, GUI.Labels, etc. When all those GUI.* calls were made inside OnGUI(), the camera abnormally disappeared.

Comment: The initial call site must be in OnGUI but you can call other methods in other classes from OnGUI and in those methods do things like GUI.Button or GUI.Label.  [From the forums.](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/37439-solved-GUI-from-outside-OnGUI(-))